# Cannot get a proper Vista / 7 theme for toolbar with wxWidgets

Tags: c++, windows-7, windows-vista, wxwidgets

I cannot get a proper theme for toolbars in Vista / 7 with wxWidgets (c++). For some unknown reason, I get gray bar now (as you can see [here](http://img691.imageshack.us/i/window1.png/)). I want it to get [this](http://img717.imageshack.us/i/window2.png/) look instead. I've linked against comctl32.lib (=> 5.82) and UXTHEME is on. Here's the code:

```
#include <wx/wx.h>

class TestAppFrame: public wxFrame
{
        public:
                TestAppFrame(wxWindow *parent,
                             wxWindowID id = wxID_ANY,
                             const wxString &title = wxT("Test"),
                             const wxPoint &position = wxDefaultPosition,
                             const wxSize &size = wxSize(373, 206),
                             long style = wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wxTAB_TRAVERSAL)
                : wxFrame(parent, id, title, position, size, style)
                {
                        wxToolBar *tb = CreateToolBar(wxNO_BORDER | wxHORIZONTAL | wxTB_FLAT);

                        tb->Realize();

                        SetToolBar(tb);
                }
};

class TestApp: public wxApp
{
        public:
                bool OnInit()
                {
                        if (!wxApp::OnInit())
                                return false;

                        wxInitAllImageHandlers();

                        TestAppFrame *frame = new TestAppFrame(NULL);

                        frame->Show(true);

                        return true;
                }
};

IMPLEMENT_APP(TestApp)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Best regards,
nhaa123

Comment: Not used wxWidgets before but what happens if you remove the wxTB_FLAT style from CreateToolBar(...)? According to http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxtoolbar.html#wxtoolbar - wxTB_FLAT Gives the toolbar a flat look (Windows and GTK only).

Comment: This has no effect, unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried the wxWidgets forums or discussion groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient rebar-like background is actually inappropriate for toolbars under Vista/7, if you look at any native applications using toolbars and not rebars or ribbons (which are, admittedly, a bit hard to find nowadays) you can see that they have the same grey background so we decided that this was the correct thing to do.

You should be able to paint the background of the toolbar on your own in `EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND` event but by default wx tries to behave conforming to the platform standards and in this case this means not using any gradients.

Comment: I found this out already myself by looking into msw/toolbar.cpp.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use wxAUIToolbar. It has the look you described and is compatible with wxToolbar, so you can use it anywhere you would use a wxToolbar.

I would point you to the documentation, except there is none. (I have an open question about that myself)